# Validating a date with symfony using sfValidatorSchema

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm using the following widget to allow a user to input a date

```
$this->widgetSchema['first_registration'] = new sfWidgetFormDate(array(
  'format' => '%month%/%year%',
  'years' => range(date('Y', time()) - 15, date('Y', time()) + 15)
));
```

The default format for a date using this widget is %month%/%day%/%year% and so that's what the default validator for this widget checks for. However, I've attempted to alter the validator...

```
$this->validatorSchema['first_registration'] = new sfValidatorDate(array(
  'date_format' => '%month%/%year%',
  'with_time' => false
));
```

This isn't working and I'm still getting an invalid error. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your widget and validator still include the day field.

All your format argument does is to prevent the day from displaying - it still exists and is being validated behind the scenes. I expect that this is where the problem is occurring.

I'd recommend the easiest fix is to default the day to 1 by over-riding the bind method on the form in question. Not sure how you are doing things, but when I am working with month/year dates I often do this in the database, as it allows native date/time formats to work correctly - same argument applies to symfony forms.

```
// untested code - i may have array structure/method signatures incorrect.
function bind($taintedValues = array(), $taintedFiles = array()) {
  $taintedValues['first_registration']['day'] = 1;
  return parent::bind($taintedValues, $taintedFiles);
}
```

Additionally, the date_format option for sfValidatorDate takes a regular expression as its argument, not a format as used in sfWidgetFormDate.